# Trouble Integrating Twitter in android. Since twitter kit is discontinued by twitter on 31 oct 2018

Tags: android, twitter, google-fabric, twitter-login

Can't integrate twitter login since yesterday. Twitter has stopped supporting its kit from oct 31,2018 no further updates they will deliver.

Fabric plugin has removed the login option from its menu. I have installed fabric as well in my android studio.

Firebase twitter also send me to the https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps
and a strange message comes "We have sunset apps.twitter.com. You can manage any of your existing apps in all of the same ways through this site."

This is not giving client secrete and twitter key. How could I integrate twitter in my application?